# Wicket: internal error in cloning object

Tags: java, object, wicket, cloning

I am programming in  wicket.I am trying to upload a file on my server.But when i am doing so i am getting an error while uploading "Error in cloning object" below is the detail error which i am getting

```
Page [Page class = com.pcmc.theka.pages.TrnThUploadTenderDocument, id = 3] couldn't be cloned to move to another pagemap
wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Internal error cloning object
    at wicket.util.lang.Objects.cloneObject(Objects.java:362)
    at wicket.markup.html.WebPage.onNewBrowserWindow(WebPage.java:337)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:163)
    at wicket.request.target.component.listener.ListenerInterfaceRequestTarget.processEvents(ListenerInterfaceRequestTarget.java:74)
    at wicket.request.compound.DefaultEventProcessorStrategy.processEvents(DefaultEventProcessorStrategy.java:65)
    at wicket.request.compound.AbstractCompoundRequestCycleProcessor.processEvents(AbstractCompoundRequestCycleProcessor.java:57)
    at wicket.RequestCycle.doProcessEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:846)
    at wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:879)
    at wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:960)
    at wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1034)
    at wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:453)
    at wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet.doGet(WicketServlet.java:215)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
 Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at wicket.util.lang.Objects.cloneObject(Objects.java:351)
    ... 33 more
```

help required......

Answer (score 2):

`java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade` is the clue. You have a reference to `ApplicationContextFacade` somewhere in your object graph, which isn't serializable, so you should try to get rid of it.

(Based on this https://community.jboss.org/message/210557, maybe you have a reference to the `ServletContext`)